# How to find complementary number of 0 to 90 on the incremental of 10

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I find the opposite number of numbers on a scale 0 to 90

**For example:**

`0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90`

where

- The complementary of 40 is 50
- the complementary of 20 is 70
- the complementary of 60 is 30

**The formula should also works for**

`1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91`

where

- The complementary of 11 is 81
- The complementary of 41 is 51

I'm trying to solve a problem where there is a 10x10 grid like:

`...
2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72, 82, 92
1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91
0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90`

And I need the formula to calculate the opposite number of the column:

input 10 → output 80

input 42 → output 52

input 70 → output 20

Comment: You don't say *opposite*, you say *complementary*.

Comment: The complementary of $20$ is not $80$ !

Comment: sorry I just editted the question

Comment: And now fix the other wrong complementaries.

Comment: so how to find the complementary of 42?

Comment: @bn. Should the complementary of 42 would depend on the scale you define it in? (and why *complementary* and not *complement*?)

Comment: I just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

$$f(n)=n+90-20\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: how do you get the 90 and 20?

Comment: it works perfectly! thank you, but what if the grid becomes 8x8?

Comment: @bn.: I don't understand what "grid" means in this context.

Comment: I mean, what if the row starts from 0, 8, 16, 24, 52, 40, 48, 56, instead of 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90

Comment: @bn.: And what would be the corresponding opposite values???

Comment: I think I got it. You got the 90 from number of ROWS・COLUMNS・ROWS, and the 20 from ROWS・2? and the 10 is the number of ROWS?

Comment: I tried it with 3x8 grid and it works nicely

Comment: can you help me again please, what if the row starts from 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and the next row follows 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19. and so on. What is the function? or should I open another question for this?

Comment: @bn.: Open another question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45361/discussion-between-bbnn-and-barak-manos).

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{opposite-of-number} = (\text{top-of-scale} + \text{bottom-of-scale}) - \mathrm{number}$$

Answer (score 1):

you want: number + complement = minimum + maximum = any other number + its complement.

So complement = minimum + maximum - number = any other number + its complement - number.