# How to find complementary number a grid block on the incremental of 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, discrete-mathematics

How to find complementary number of 0 to 90 on the incremental of 10

How can I find the opposite number of numbers on a scale 0 to 90

**For example:**

I'm trying to solve a problem where there is a 10x10 grid like:

`90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99
...
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
0 ,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9`

And I need the formula to calculate the opposite number of the column:

input 18 → output 11

input 56 → output 53

input 51 → output 58

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find complementary number of 0 to 90 on the incremental of 10](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924910/how-to-find-complementary-number-of-0-to-90-on-the-incremental-of-10)

Comment: No offense, but your two questions look rather identical. Let me know if you think otherwise, and I will retract my vote-to-close.

Comment: @barak it's identical but it's the same. and you told me to open a new question in the comment.

Comment: I wrote that comment assuming that you had a different question to ask.

Comment: actually it's different, because the answer seems to be different too $$f(n)=n+90-20\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10}\right\rfloor$$ doesn't work on this question.

Comment: OK, I'll retract my vote-to-close. But something doesn't quite work out right in your description: "the opposite number of the column" - $18$ and $11$ are in different columns!

Comment: @barak oh ya! really sorry I just changed it to row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45372/discussion-between-bbnn-and-barak-manos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the first digit, replace the second digit $i$ with $9-i$.

So, if you get $73$, the result will be $76$. $7$ because it is the first digit, and $6$ because $6=9-3$.

Comment: what if it's a 8x8 grid?

Comment: @bbnn convert the number to base $8$ and repeat the process I described above, switching the second digit $i$ with $7-i$ instead. The convert back to decimal.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work with 8x8. I tried opposite of 11, and it gives me 12 instead of 15. Thank you so much for your answer btw.

Comment: do you have any arithmetic formula like in here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924910/how-to-find-complementary-number-of-0-to-90-on-the-incremental-of-10/1924930#1924930 ?

Comment: @bbnn It works for $8\times 8$. You start with $11$ which is $13$ in base $8$, and you turn that into $14$ (because $4=7-3$) which is  $12$ in base $8$. That's correct because the second row is $8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15$.

Comment: @bbnn An arithmetic formula would be to look at the remainder when dividing the number by $10$ (or $8$ in an $8\times 8$ grid), which is the same as the second digit. I'm sure you can work it out.